# SQL select statement compare formatted date

Tags: mysql, date

I am having some problem when trying to write SQL statement to get the records with date larger than today's. Here is my SQL statement:

```
SELECT e.eventID, e.eventName, e.eventDesc, e.eventTime, e.eventX, e.eventY, e.eventBy, e.eventPic, 
e.eventAddr, e.eventDate
FROM mydb.event e INNER JOIN mydb.bookedevent be ON e.eventID = be.eventID 
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(e.eventDate, '%Y-%m-%d')  >= CURDATE()
```

My date in event table is in varchar() and in this format: 22/11/2014. I have some records which meets this criteria but I am getting 0 records returned. So, I went to test to get the formatted date column by this SQL statement:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(e.eventDate, '%Y/%m/%d') FROM mydb.event e
```

And I am getting a few rows of null record.

Comment: You should probably change and use a proper datetime field in the database and then you can use all of the sql date functionality available rather than trying to parse text.

Comment: But is there any way to convert the string to date time? I have experience in SQLite but not MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your date is stored as varchar and to convert it to real date you need **[str_to_date](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)**

```
select str_to_date('22/11/2014','%d/%m/%Y') as date ;
+------------+
| date       |
+------------+
| 2014-11-22 |
+------------+
```

So in the comparison you should use as above.

Note : Its better to store the dates in mysql native date data types instead of `varchar`

Answer (score 0):

Is it works in mysql.

```
SELECT e.eventID, e.eventName, e.eventDesc, e.eventTime, e.eventX, e.eventY, e.eventBy, e.eventPic, 
e.eventAddr, e.eventDate
FROM mydb.event e INNER JOIN mydb.bookedevent be ON e.eventID = be.eventID 
 WHERE DATEDIFF(str_to_date(CURDATE(),'%d/%m/%Y'), 
          str_to_date(e.eventDate,'%d/%m/%Y')) >= 0
```